# Sql Parameters supplied for object 'Firm' which is not a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[**Structure tables and result query on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d59e5/1)

I want use query:

```
INSERT INTO Firm('name', 'name_original', 'id_city', 'id_service', 'id_firm')
VALUES
('РЭД-АВТО ООО', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '1429'),
('УМ-3 ЗАО ', 'УМ-3 ЗАО ', '73041', '2', '49806'),
('ООО West Hole', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '10004');
```

But i get errors:

```
Parameters supplied for object 'Firm' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.: 
INSERT INTO Firm('name', 'name_original', 'id_city', 'id_service', 'id_firm') 
VALUES 
('РЭД-АВТО ООО', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '1429'), 
('УМ-3 ЗАО ', 'УМ-3 ЗАО ', '73041', '2', '49806'), 
('ООО West Hole', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '10004')
```

Tell me please why i get errors and how correct insert data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your column names.

```
INSERT INTO Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm)
VALUES
('РЭД-АВТО ООО', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '1429'),
('УМ-3 ЗАО ', 'УМ-3 ЗАО ', '73041', '2', '49806'),
('ООО West Hole', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '10004');
```

Comment: thanks for the question though as it fixed my problems as well

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to 'stringify' your column names in the `INSERT INTO` statement. Column names are expected idetifiers

calling

```
INSERT INTO Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm)
```

with your VALUES will give a successful result

Answer (score 1):

For Example:

`Insert into TableName ( Name,ID ) THEN Values ( 'Joe',2).`

**Note:** The data type of column name should match with the data that you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm)
VALUES ('РЭД-АВТО ООО', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '1429')
INSERT INTO Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm)
VALUES('УМ-3 ЗАО ', 'УМ-3 ЗАО ', '73041', '2', '49806')
INSERT INTO Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm)
VALUES ('ООО West Hole', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '10004')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Firm TABLE(name NVARCHAR(100), name_original NVARCHAR(100), id_city NVARCHAR(100)
          , id_service NVARCHAR(100), id_firm NVARCHAR(100)) 

INSERT INTO @Firm(name, name_original, id_city, id_service, id_firm) 
VALUES 
(N'РЭД-АВТО ООО', N'РЭД-АВТО ООО', N'73041', N'1', N'1429'),  --<-- Prefix with 'N'
('РЭД-АВТО ООО', 'РЭД-АВТО ООО', '73041', '2', '1429')

SELECT * FROM @Firm
╔══════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║     name     ║ name_original ║ id_city ║ id_service ║ id_firm ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ РЭД-АВТО ООО ║ РЭД-АВТО ООО  ║   73041 ║          1 ║    1429 ║ --<-- with Prefix 'N'
║ ???-???? ??? ║ ???-???? ???  ║   73041 ║          2 ║    1429 ║ --<-- without Prefix 'N'
╚══════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

**Note for**   **unicode characters**.

```
Do not forget to Prefix your passed strings with `N` as your strings contained 
unicode characters.
```